# git push hangs and does nothing

Tags: git-push

I'm new to git and testing it out. I've been able to clone a friends repository make small local changes and commit.

I'd like to now test pushing my local changes to the remote repository but unfortunately when I try to do a push

$ git push `<my friends remote repository`>
   <---- hangs here waiting ..I break out by ctr-c

Here is some info showing my current status,

$ git remote show origin
  Fetch URL: git://codaset.com/nickbmarine/nickspix.git
  Push  URL: git://codaset.com/nickbmarine/nickspix.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    Refactor tracked
    master   tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)

Any idea's?

Comment: Similar problem here. Somebody says it might be a buggy router. No idea yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try pushing to git using http:// instead git://. If it works this way probably your router is blocking the git port.

Comment: My fix was this, but the reverse: https:// to git@

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same problem when running GIT from a command prompt (Win 8.1) within a VirtualBox. I found that if you simply press a key on the keyboard that you will be prompted for your username, and then all is ok. It seems that the prompt was stuck, awaiting keyboard input.

Answer (score 2):

On your current branch, use the following command to update your config

$ git config --global user.email "email@example.com"

This worked for me!

Comment: Are you sure setting `user.email` can clear the hangs and push would start to work??

Answer (score 1):

If the above doesn't work, then its likely because you need to (config) your name and email before you can do the (push) to the online github repository. You can submit (config) your name & email through the Git Bash command line by entering these 2 commands:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"                 //not your GitHub username

$ git config --global user.email "email@example.com"        //must be yout GitHub email
```

► After this, you can then run [$ git push] to upload the changes

Answer (score 1):

For me, this issue was caused by the network. When I changed to a different network and tried again, it worked. Git server was on Amazon Lightsail, which sometimes refuses connection from certain networks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Github Desktop. Pushing would cause the app to hang with this message:

> Total 646 (delta 320), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0

Eventually I fixed this by removing the repo from Github desktop and then adding it back.